# How to map object in strapi V4 in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, strapi

In strapi v4 the get respon api it changed from array to object. This body of postman in my local strapi api and if we try to show the raw using `stringify` we can see I have access to the Api. As we can see below it have 2 keys `data` and `meta`

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 2,
    "attributes": {
        "firstBtn": "Fan",
        "secondBtn": "Cookies",
        "thirdBtn": "HDMI",
        "fourthBtn": "Laptop",
        "createdAt": "2022-06-08T05:40:13.871Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-06-08T05:40:14.591Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-06-08T05:40:14.588Z",
        "zerobutton": "Spesial Discount"
    }
},
"meta": {}
```

}

When I try to iterate through the array using map I got a few error like this

`Uncaught TypeError: button.map is not a function`

**another error**

`react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

I try to find the doc or another solution but strapi v4 is new so I didnt really understand how we map through the object. This is one of my react component when taking get strapi. This is my code and thanks in advance

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { Container } from "@mui/system";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const ButtonFam = () => {
    const [button,setButton] = useState([])
    const keyofbutton = Object.keys(button) //check the key object
    const detailedbutton = button.data 
    console.log(keyofbutton) 
    console.log("detailedata is an array " + Array.isArray(detailedbutton)) // CHECK IF THECONST ARRAY OR NOT
    console.log(detailedbutton) // log the array
    useEffect(() => {
            fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/button-links/',{
                headers: {
                    Authorization:
                    'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MywiaWF0IjoxNjU0NTA5MDE1LCJleHAiOjE2NTcxMDEwMTV9.HOGhkG--nRYbPQKmOsNo75VAOKQydu1kw8o8MncdhdE',
                },
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => setButton(data))
            .then(console.log("Data success"))
            .catch((err) => { 
                console.log(err)
                
    
            })
            
        },[])

    return (
        //try to map the api result
        <>
        //when we print using stringify we can see the api already in there but cannot map
        <p>{JSON.stringify(button)}</p> 
         //this throw the second error
        {
            button.data.map((btn) => {
                return <li>{btn}</li>
            })
        }
       //this throw the first error
        {
            button.map((btn) => {
                return <li>{btn}</li>
            })
        }
       
        </>
     );
}
 
export default ButtonFam;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your content 'button links' is probably Single Types and not Collection Types.

collection types return something like this

```json
{
  "data":
  [
    {"id":1,"attributes":{"title":"one"}}, 
    {"id":2,"attributes":{"title":"two"}}, 
    {"id":3,"attributes":{"title":"three"}}
  ], 
  "meta": {}
}
```

Single Types on the other hand.

```json
{
  "data":
   {
      "id":1,
      "attributes":
         { 
            "text":"one.", 
             "sectionTitle":"two",
             "active":true
         }
   },
   "meta":{}
}
```

So to map your object first you'll have to turn it to an array using:

```js
Object.values(object)
```

And for you it should be something like this:

```js
Object.values(button.data.attributes)
.map((btn) => {
  return <li>{btn}</li>
})
```